# SSIS No Tables or Views Could be Loaded Error with Oracle 12c ODBC

Tags: ssis, odbc, oracle12c

We are trying to set up an ODBC Destination object in a SSIS package and getting a "No tables or views could be loaded" error (see screen shot below). The schema is relatively new and we are able to do this with an older schema in the same database.

Some observations:

1. We are able to successfully make a connection to the schema both through the Windows ODBC administrator and from the SSIS connection manager.
2. We are able to display tables from ANOTHER schema that is the same database.
3. We are also able to display tables in the schema causing the error if we do so by connecting to another schema (see more below).

More on #3 above. Let's say we have schemas/users MySchemaA and MySchemaB and MySchemaB is the one we want. If we connect directly to MySchemaB, it doesn't work. But if we grant MySchemaA rights to see tables in MySchemaB and connect to MySchemaA... we can indirectly see the tables granted in MySchemaB through the connection to MySchemaA. Hopefully clear as mud.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Since this is a new schema, does something need to be setup on the DB side to allow this?

We using Oracle 12c and have installed the necessary drivers. Also using ODBC administrator 32-bit to set up a system DSN.

[image]

Comment: Does the user you're using for the connection have the same permissions to the new schema as the old schema(s)?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. In Oracle, user and schema are the same. In a sense we are connecting to a new schema using that schema's user name.

Comment: I was asking because I use the Attunity Oracle Connector for SSIS, and I specify a username (and password) in the connection manager that is definitely not the same as the schema name. I also know my company's Oracle admin has to grant permissions to the user before I can see the tables on my end.

Comment: That is likely because you are doing what I described in #3 above. You are connecting to schema/user "MySchamaA" and viewing another schema/user "MySchemaB" from there.

Comment: Most likely, yes, but then, I'm not an Oracle admin, so I don't really know the details of what happens on that side.
I still believe this is a permissions error. Make sure your user/schema has permissions to access `dba_tables`. It's my understanding that SSIS uses this table to populate the list of tables you can select in the "Name of table" dropdown.

Comment: We double checked the privileges between the schema that works and the one that does not. The only differences are the one that works has two additional privileges "CREATE DATABASE LINK" and "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW".

Comment: I would try adding those permissions, one at a time, to the new schema/user, to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: We are putting a request to do that. In the meantime, not sure it's a permissions issue now. We tried using an Oracle Attunity driver instead of ODBC and that works as expected. So doesn't make sense it's something with permissions. We can use the Attunity one, but still would like to solve the problem with the ODBC driver because a lot of our solutions use it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to offer more help on this one, but it now sounds like an issue with your DSN configuration, since you said the Attunity connectors worked fine. Do you have separate DSNs configured for each schema connection?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck?